# AWS CDK - IAM : how to get the list of users IDs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, aws-organizations, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm developing a typescript app with cdk and I need to fetch the list of the existing users from my organisation.
Till now I can't find a way to do with cdk or cfn, did anyone run into a similar situation ?
thanks

Answer (score -1):

The straightforward solution is to insert a JS SDK call to the IAM Identity Store [ListUsers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-identitystore/classes/listuserscommand.html) API (or other APIs if you are not using SSO) into your CDK code.

This code will get called during the CDK's [synth process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-context).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this is generally considered a bad practice because it breaks one of the principles of CDK apps - determinism. Maybe an alternative suggestion may be considered, such as performing the API call in a custom resource at deploy time.

Comment: @gshpychka  Really?  So, in your opinion, the CDK's [context methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_methods) like `StringParameter.valueFromLookup` are non-deterministic anti-patterns?  These methods similarly make synth-time API "get resource" calls.  The results are cachable = committable as artefacts = deterministic.  As the CDK best practice docs put it, [Make decisions at synthesis time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-synth)!

Comment: Yes, if you don't commit your `cdk.context.json` to VCS and your app makes those calls on every synth, that's an anti-pattern. Your answer does not mention caching, and making calls to the web is specifically called out in the best practices guide.

Comment: @gshpychka The answer's [second link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-context) covers committing the context at synth-time.  To justify your first comment, you might want to explain how your deploy-time solution is compatible with your second comment. How is making deploy-time API calls with a Custom Resource _better_ at keeping the CDK artefacts updated?  Will your CR Lambda handler write back to VCS?  Can you point to a reference implementation?

Comment: I am not looking for an argument here, I'm merely pointing out that the best practices guide explicitly advises against making SDK calls in the CDK code, so it should be worth mentioning that in the answer.

Comment: @gshpychka Nothing personal, but is saying "best practice" without support constructive?  I see 3 comments, 3 appeals to "best practice" and 0 references.   We have different views about the docs.  Fine.  You don't want to argue.  Also fine.  But when competing views are supported by specific references, the community is able to judge for themselves!  All good, though.

Comment: Sure, I was referring to the official Best Practices doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps
`For example, you could use an AWS SDK to retrieve some information from your AWS account while synthesizing your app. Recognize that doing so will result in additional credential setup requirements, increased latency, and a chance, however small, of failure every time you run cdk synth.` and `Even strictly read-only calls are not necessarily safe. `

Comment: Hurrah! We agree after all: _Synth-time SDK read calls are a useful feature, just be careful!_.

Comment: My point was that it should be mentioned that it is explicitly discouraged in the best practices guide, as it's not clear from the answer text that it's not considered a good practice.